# ArrayList vs Generic List On Memory allocation in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to clear concepts regarding Memory allocation of ArrayList vs Generic List, if both are value type and if both are reference type. Could any one hhelp to clear out?

Comment: what is your concern about Memory Allocation? just curious.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference in memory use is when you store a Value type. The ArrayList will have to Box (copy) the value. A boxed value will be placed on the Heap, consuming at least an extra header block (ca 20 bytes).

But this will only be significant when you store many millions of items, not something you do all the time.

Comment: Array List need boxing when storing value type thats why it consume more memory and is not purely reference type.is it?

Comment: The ArrayList itself is still a pure reference type.

Answer (score 1):

They are both reference types. The only difference is that `ArrayList` is weakly typed. Value types such as int, bool etc that are stored in it are boxed into the `object` type. Then, you unbox them when you cast each item in the `ArrayList`.

Because everything is boxed into an object, you can store objects of different types in an `ArrayList`.

Generic List is strongly typed, that is, it can store objects of the same type. There's no boxing, so it's more efficient.

The boxing process allocates more memory to encapsulate the object into the weak type `object`.

If you stored only objects of reference types in the ArrayList, then boxing is not used, rather another mechanism is used called reference conversion.

Comment: Boxing only happens for Value types, your answer is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

- `ArrayList` is a Reference Type,but not Typesafe and less efficient
- `List<T>` or Generic list is a Reference Type,but is Type Safe and efficient

Here is the SO post on Memory Allocation of Reference Types
[How memory is allocated to reference types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754903/how-memory-is-allocated-to-reference-types-in-c)